# Calling method with the specified argument

Tags: c#

There is a dictionary list to store argument one by one, and a method need to be called by the parameters from the list. Is there a easy way to do this? Thanks

```
IDictionary<string, string> argDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
argDic.add("a", "100");
argDic.add("b", "200");
argDic.add("c", "300");

private void Run(string a, string b, string c){
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}

Run(argDic["a"], argDic["b"], argDic["c"]);
```

This is only a example, the dicitonary list is not fixed, there are many random variables in it. The frist argument "a" will be found in the dictionary object, if it is matched, and the parameter "a" value 100 in dictionay will be used.

**Update:**
Sorry, I should use a picture to illustrate. There is a job schedule, when the task is scheduled, the binding method on every task node should be invoked by its name and parameters. So the method and its argument are specified througth the configuration.

[image]

```
**Task001:**
Invoked Method: MethodA(string a, string b, string c);
Variable Key: ["a", "b", "c"]
Variable Value: ["100", "200", "300"]

**Taks002:**
Invoked Method: MethodB(int d, int e);
Variable Key: ["d", "e"]
Variable Value: ["9", "99"]

private void MethodA(string a, string b, string c){
        Console.WriteLine("Hello the string World!");
    }

private void MethodB(int d, int e){
        Console.WriteLine("Hello the int World!");
}
```

Comment: If argDic["a"] isnt found, there will be an exception thrown, the parameter always need to be matched in the dictionary list, then the method can be called. This scenario is used to invoke a specified method with dynamic variables.

Comment: What do you mean **easy**? To omit `argDic[]` part like `Run("a","b","c")`?;

Comment: @shingo, If the reflection is an option, and get the meta of the method. The every argument name to compare and look up in the dictionary list.

Comment: I still cant understand, why reflection? is there any relationship between the paramenter's name and the dictionary key? if so, how about the parameter's value, do they have separated usage? if not, then `"d"` cannot pass to `int d`.

Comment: The code "`Run(argDic["a"], argDic["b"], argDic["c"]);`" is simple and easy to write I think, what are you discontented with?

Comment: The method name, parameter name are configurated in the job schedule system. The variable list contained the parameter name and value, even it's type, if there is an integer type d exist, a tuple object(contain name, type and value property) required rather than a dicitonary object(key-value).

Comment: Check the update on my answer

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me that this is the best approach:

```
IDictionary<string, string> argDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {   "a", "100" },
    {   "b", "200" },
    {   "c", "300" },
};

IDictionary<string, Action<IDictionary<string, string>>> runDict = new Dictionary<string, Action<IDictionary<string, string>>>()
{
    { "MethodA", d => MethodA(d["a"], d["b"], d["c"]) },
    { "MethodB", d => MethodB(int.Parse(d["d"]), int.Parse(d["e"])) },
}

runDict["MethodA"](argDict);
```

Answer (score -2):

Better you can have a class with all the possible types of arguments you may have and pass that class as argument to the method, that will help you to avoid type casting as well and later you can have new members added to the class.
Ex:

```
class methodArgs
{
  public int param1 {get;set;}
  public string param2 {get;set;}
  public double param3 {get;set;}
  public bool param4 {get;set;}
}
```

and set it like:

```
methodArgs obj = new methodArgs();
obj.param1 = 10;
obj.param2 = "Hello World";
obj.param3 = 10.10;
obj.param4 = false;
```

and pass it like:

```
Run(obj);
```

Answer (score -2):

You said this is an example, but what are the actual parameters defined on the `Run` method?

You can use Reflection to dynamically get the MethodInfo of the Run method and supply arguments based on what data you currently have, including checking whether a particular key exists in the dictionary.

You can use a params array as input and use that to invoke the Run method which will be defined as:

```
private void Run(params string[] data) {}
```

Can be used with variable number of arguments:

```
Run("a", "b");
Run("c", "d", "e");
```

#### Update

Given your updated answer, I see that you want to have a job-dispatching mechanism that calls methods dynamically, based on their name and some arguments sent as text. C# has beautiful and powerful features to do this, basically Reflection. Here's an example that illustrates everything, including a basic version where Reflection is used (in case you have to use that).

With reflection, you can also inspect the parameter list and do matching based on the parameter names if you need (this isn't shown below, let me know if you need help with that)

```
/// <summary>
/// Runner should not contain dangerous methods! Access control and security aspects must be considered.
/// </summary>
public class Runner
{
    /// <summary>Just to illustrate</summary>
    public int CallCount { get; set; }

    internal void MethodA(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        CallCount++;
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello the string World {a}, {b}, {c}!");
    }

    internal void MethodB(int d, int e)
    {
        CallCount++;
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello the int World, sum = {d + e}!");
    }

    internal void MethodC(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e)
    {
        CallCount++;
        Console.WriteLine($"Welcome to the world of the strings {a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}!");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new Runner();
        ExecuteMethodWithSwitch(instance, "MethodA", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
        ExecuteMethod(instance, "MethodA", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
        ExecuteMethod(instance, "MethodB", 111, 222);
        ExecuteMethod(instance, "MethodC", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "monkey", "banana");
        //this is a testing-related statement
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(instance.CallCount == 4, "CallCount should be 4");
        Console.WriteLine($"Instance has been called {instance.CallCount} times...");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// NOT RECOMMENDED WAY: Just use a switch statement and convert arguments like a noob.
    /// Only good thing about this is perhaps that is has more compile time checks.
    /// Incorrect arguments = exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o"></param>
    /// <param name="methodName"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    private static void ExecuteMethodWithSwitch(Runner runner, string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        switch (methodName)
        {
            case nameof(runner.MethodA):
                runner.MethodA(args[0]?.ToString(), args[1]?.ToString(), args[2]?.ToString());
                break;
            case nameof(runner.MethodB):
                var int1 = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
                var int2 = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
                runner.MethodB(int1, int2);
                break;
            case nameof(runner.MethodC):
                runner.MethodC(args[0]?.ToString(), args[1]?.ToString(), args[2]?.ToString(), args[3]?.ToString(), args[4]?.ToString());
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException($"Method with name {methodName} not known", nameof(methodName));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// RECOMMENDED WAY: Use reflection like a pro who actually likes C# and .NET.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o"></param>
    /// <param name="methodName"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    private static void ExecuteMethod(object o, string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        //beautiful, no? Will continue to work even for newly added methods.
        var type = o.GetType();
        //NonPublic to get the 'internal' methods
        var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        methodInfo.Invoke(o, args);
    }
}
```